# PHP undefined array key error MSSQL and PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I keep getting this error:

> Warning: Undefined array key "user_id" in C:\laragon\www\auth\public\details.php on line 23
> ID:

This is the code:

```
<?php
$pdo = require __DIR__ . '/../src/bootstrap.php'; 

$user_id=$_GET['user_id'];
if(!is_numeric($user_id))
{
    echo "Data Error";
    exit;
}

 $sql = 'SELECT user_id,email from users
        WHERE user_id = :user_id';

    $statement = db()->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $statement->execute();

    $row= $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    var_dump($row);
    // die();

echo " ID: $row[user_id],";
```

I can see I am getting an array with the User_id and email this is the output to screen I get:
I have tried wrapping user_id in single quotes, double quotes, no quotes. Nothing seems to work.

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["user_id"]=> string(2) "27" ["email"]=> string(15) "billy@gmail.com" } }
Warning: Undefined array key "user_id" in C:\laragon\www\auth\public\details.php on line 23
ID: ,
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2019
Laragon for the webhost

I have tried wrapping user_id in single quotes, double quotes, no quotes. Nothing seems to work.

Error was the same

Comment: *"I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2019"* then  why have you tagged [[tag:sql-server-2012]]? Which are you *actually* using, 2012 or 2019?

Comment: Because you're getting an array containing all the rows in the result set, surely you'll need to `echo $row[0]['user_id']` to show the first one? Your `var_dump()` shows that you have an array of arrays. As there should only be one row in the database with that user_id because you'll have that set as a unique column, there's no need for `fetchAll()` here.

Comment: I couldn't find a tag for sql-server-2019 2012 seemed to be the newest. I am considering moving to MySQL the support for MSSQL is much smaller and the cost too. Thanks anyway.

Comment: SQL Server 2022 is the newest, and there's tags for all [SQL Server releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+or+sql-server-20*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$row` variable is an array of arrays. You need to access the individual row first, before you can access its column.

```php
echo "ID: ".$row[0]['user_id'];
```

Since you are filtering on a single User ID, it's probably better to use `fetch()`, which will fetch just one row.

```php
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "ID: ".$row['user_id'];
```

Comment: $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "ID: ".$row['user_id'];

That did it! You can't imagine how close I have been so many times! I just never got the correct combination.

Thank you so much!